# WPF TextChanged puts the cursor after first letter

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an Infragistics grid, with a cell with the following EditorStyle (set via static resource):

```
<Style x:Key="ProgramName_EditorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}}, Path=DataContext}" />
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding DataItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
        <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="TextChangedHandler"/>        
    </Style>
```

This is the code behind for TextChangedHandler:

```
void TextChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<string> e)
        {
            var editor = sender as XamTextEditor;
            if (editor == null)
                return;

            var record = editor.DataContext as DataRecord;
            if (record == null)
                return;

            var list = record.DataPresenter.DataContext as MyProgramListViewModel;
            if (list == null)
                return;

            var data = record.DataItem as MyProgramSummaryViewModel;
            if (data == null)
                return;

            MyProgramSummaryViewModel toBeAdded = null;

            if (data.ReinsuranceSummary == null)
                toBeAdded =
                    MyProgramSummaryViewModel.Create(
                        new ProgramSummary { EnteredDate = DateTime.UtcNow, EditedDate = DateTime.UtcNow }, list);

            if (toBeAdded != null)
            {
                data.Summary = toBeAdded.Summary;
                data.Master = toBeAdded.Master;

            }
            data.Name = e.NewValue;
            Debug.Print(e.NewValue);

        }
```

The problem happens when I start typing in the cell. 
If I want to enter abc, I get bca. What happens is that after the first character is entered, the cursor is set back to the beginning of the cell, making the first letter last. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should call at the end of your TextChangedHandler

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Are you sure the text is not changed in code behind?

Comment: Yes. It looks like there is a conflict between <setter Property="Text"... and <EventSetter Event="TextChanged"...> I am digging more into it.

Comment: If you decide to put the cursor to the end it can be done but maybe it's better to find the problem rather then to workaround before investigating